# Car failed to change the route error in anyLogic

Tags: anylogic, traffic-simulation

I am Simulating the road traffic model in **anyLogic**. I am making a cross road network of **four** roads using **one** intersection and **two** car source. I have used select Output5 twice as seen in screenshot below.
[image: Image of Road Network]

Here road on **East** side is named as **RoadE**, road on **West** side is named as **roadW**, road on **North** side is named as **roadN** and road on **South** side is named as **roadS**.

Logic:-
[image: Logic Of road Network]

Every time i am trying to run the model, it is throwing same exception as :
[image: Image of Error]

Why this agent is not able to choose right lane?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure that the road segment (where the car comes from) is long enough. If it is too short, some cars might not have enough space and time to switch into the required lane.

Just make your bottom road a little longer and it will work.

Answer (score 1):

Just see on lines consists from points on crossroad: right way does not conntected with left road. Car cant ride left from right way, and because it try to cange lane.
Do it herself (select crossroad, and then double click on rectangle on the end of way).
Offcorse, if your cars can ride left from right way)